# see the menu in all views with vue and css

Tags: css, vue.js

Hello I am trying to implement my menu that I have created with css in all views, for example in my home view I want to invoke it as I saw an example on the web like this:

```
        <template>
        <Fragment>
        <menu></menu>
            <div class="portada">
                <menu></menu>
                <div id="desarrollofrontend">
                 Test Menu
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h1>Test Menu Home</h1> 
                    <h3>Description home</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
        </template>

        <script>
        import menu from '../components/Head/menu.vue'

        export default {
            components: { menu }
        } 
        </script>
```

But so far nothing works for me, I'm really new to this

This is my view of my home page, I have my menu created with scss, in the `<menu> </menu>` tags it is how I saw some examples on the web but it does not work for me

Any recommendations to make it work?

Comment: What does `doesn't work for me` mean exactly? Please check [ask]

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: add the code of the `<menu>` component